# Centering an Element Relative to Another Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, centering

I have an element that should be horizontally centered to another element. The CSS for the centered element is so (I removed uneccesary code):

```
#center-element{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I have to do so using vanilla JS. I tried:

```
var targetPos = target.getBoundingClientRect();
centerDiv.style.top = (targetPos.top + targetPos.height) + "px";
centerDiv.style.left = (targetPos.left + (targetPos.width  / 2)) + "px";
```

But that is off. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/277z1sah/)

Comment: ...why not just give both divs the same style? All you need is width:75% and text-align:center on both

Comment: Yes, but in my code (not here), it isn't text.

Comment: hard to help with a misleading example, but you can try display:inline-block and margin:0 auto; on the image or element you want to center

Comment: Well, it needs to be a flexbox, so I can't do any `display` fancy stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//Somehow center the div here
var target = document.getElementById("target");
var centerDiv = document.getElementById("centerDiv");
var targetPos = target.getBoundingClientRect();
centerDiv.style.top = targetPos.bottom + "px";
centerDiv.style.left = targetPos.left + (target.offsetWidth - centerDiv.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
```

```css
#target {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
}
#centerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
  This is the div
</div>
<div id="centerDiv">
  This is supposed to be horizontally centered <em>to the div element above</em>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using flexbox. You can wrap both div inside a container div and apply `display:flex;` on that container.

```css
#target {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#centerDiv {
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: absolute; */
  text-align:center;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  width:75%;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div id="target">
  This is the div
</div>
<div id="centerDiv">
  This is supposed to be horizontally centered <em><br/>to the div element above</em>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when a flexbox is inside a flexbox?

Comment: you can use it. it doesn't break the layout.

Comment: but you can mostly align text with `text-align:center;` and div with `margin:0 auto;`